# Is there a ring buffer implementation in the standard gcc distribution?

Tags: c, gcc, circular-buffer

I want to use a ring buffer but do not want to implement my own if one already exists. Does the standard gcc distribution have one?

Comment: Nope - you'll have to implement your own.  Look here: http://www.kigen.de/development/c/ringbuffers/

Answer (score 3):

Some alternatives not directly in *gcc*,

- In wikipedia you can find a [POSIX circular buffer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer#Optimized_POSIX_implementation)
- Zed Shaw has [a circular buffer chapter](http://c.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex44.html) on his C book about
- The [boost library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/circular_buffer/doc/circular_buffer.html) has one for C++: